# how to copy the location of a input excel sheet and use the same location for saving a new excel sheet

Tags: excel

Please suggest some answer.
1.The script will give a pop up box which will ask the give the input excel.

```
Set ObjFSO = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

SPREADSHEET_PATH = ObjFSO.GetOpenFileName("Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx),*.xls;*.xlsx")
```

1. Now after doing all the validations i am going to create a new excel sheet wth updated value. and i am using

   strSSFileName = "C:\users\Desktop\New.xlsx"
   Set xlApp1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   set xlBook = xlApp1.WorkBooks.add()
   xlBook.saveAs(strSSFileName)

I dont want HARDCODE the location as it will become location specific always.

Please suggest some answer.

Comment: So what is your issue exactly? Do you want to overwrite the file whose name you got from the GetOpenFileName call?

Comment: i want a new excel to be placed in the same location dynamically while running the script.

Comment: Flow of script:
1. It will ask for input excel.
2. Acrdng to the logic it will do the validation.
3. After doing this it will capture the data in a new excel sheet and i have to place it in the same location where i got the input excel. But i want it to be dynamic. Dnt want to "HARDCODE" the location. As it will become a "LOCATION specific"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you already have the location, i.e. `SPREADSHEET_PATH`. You can extract the path from the full path and filename, and then save your new file by using the extracted path and adding your new filename, e.g. `xlBook.SaveAs(extractedPath & "\" & "New.xls")`.

**Edit:**
This would save the file in the same directory but a different name

```
Dim extractedPath As String
extractedPath = Replace(SPREADSHEET_PATH, ".xls", " NEW.xls")
xlBook.SaveAs(extractedPath)
```

Comment: Sorry, it is throwing an error "Object defined error". and pointing to the location where i wrote xlBook.SaveAs(SPREADSHEET_PATH & "\" & "New.xls") i wrote it in this manner.                         
FYI,  SPREADSHEET_PATH = ObjFSO.GetOpenFileName("Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx),*.xls;*.xlsx")
Please suggest what to do now?

Comment: You will need to extract the filename without file suffix, e.g. by replacing .xlsx with empty string.

Comment: Can you please elaborate??

Comment: Quetion is how i will extract the filename?